# Making a research "by words" in a LINQ to SQL request

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm facing a problem concerning the results i need to get with a request.

this is what i use right now:

```
v = v.Where(i => i.Intitule.Contains(Intitule));
```

Intitule is a string containing what the user writes within a textbox.

**For instance :**

if intitule contains the following text : " this is a comment"

and if a make a research using those keys: "this is"

It works perfectly

BUT if i make the research using " this comment"

It's not working anymore...

Basically, i need the research to be done on every words...

I hope i'm clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx):

```
Intitule = "%" + String.Join("%", Intitule.Split(' ')) + "%";
v = v.Where(i => SqlMethods.Like(i.Intitule,Intitule));
```

Comment: I think I used extra `%` chars, you can remove extra chars, but doesn't change anything in your search.

Comment: Thank you i think this is what i looking for but i have en error:

"An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property string.Split(params.char[])

Comment: @ArnaudAdigard, Funny mistake I made (I wrote string.Split :), check the code right now, it should be correct.